# Programmatic select() on input type number not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, select, input, focus, preact

If I have an `input` element with type `number` trying to programmatically call the `select()` function on it won't work in Safari mobile .

When running this code

```
const el = document.querySelector(`#${FIELD1} input`);
if (el) {
 setTimeout(() => {
    el.focus();
    el.select();
    el.setSelectionRange(0, 9999);
  }, 100);
}
```

The focus will work on all platforms, but the selection will only work in Chrome.

Is there any official info on this bug? Any way to go around it?

I tried `el.setSelectionRange(0,99)` as suggested in old posts but it seems to not work anymore (and it shouldn't as it's not in the W3C specs for that element).

*PS:* I'm using Preact.

EDIT: the problem is focused on iOS it actually works on Safari desktop.

I created a minimal reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/q86m6kv01q please try it navigating on your device to: https://q86m6kv01q.codesandbox.io/

Comment: Can you call click() instead?

Comment: I cannot try in Safari but `select()` is working fine for me in Firefox. You also have problems in Firefox? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Cannot call `click()` but the problem would persist in that case as well unless the click is a real one and not a synthetic one.
Firefox works ok, the problem is only on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking the select picker UI on iOS requires a user gesture. This is done so that it's not possible to trigger system UI randomly (such as on page load).